# Coding4Fun InputPrompt style text box

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm trying to style the Coding4Fun InputPrompt control to set a border on the textbox element and change the unselected colour in code.

I've not been able to find any examples, and visual studio doesn't recognise the control properly (InputPrompt is displayed in red with no intellisense, but the project runs fine).

I've managed to set some colours and update the buttons, but no success on the textbox.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Here is what I have so far:

```
var input = new InputPrompt
{
    Title = "Title",
    Message = "My Message",
    IsCancelVisible = true,
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xCC, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)),
    Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
};

input.Completed += input_Completed;
input.InputScope = new InputScope
{
    Names = {new InputScopeName() {NameValue = InputScopeNameValue.TelephoneNumber}}
};

foreach (var button in input.ActionPopUpButtons)
{
    button.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    button.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    button.Margin = new Thickness(0,5,0,0);
}

input.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5.0);
input.Show();
```

Comment: Did you ever try to use Blend for Visual Studio? Probably you can easier adjust your control with Blend.

Comment: I'll take a look, cheers

Comment: [HERE is the course from Microsoft Virtual Academy for using Blend with VS2013](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/designing-your-xaml-ui-with-blend-jump-start-8260?l=uMDU0jKy_1404984382) . It could help you.